# Creating an Excel user-defined function to look up another workbook and return an array spilling over the calling cell and its neighbor

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

Suppose I have two workbooks in the same folder: `TargetFile` and `SourceFile`, where the function `GetTwoLines()` is saved in `TargetFile`.

I would like to fix the code of the function `GetTwoLines()` in order to search the `SourceFile` for the cell content whose address is passed to the function.

After finding the row number in `SourceFile`, I need to:

1- get the content of the cell .Range("B" & RowNum + 1) in `SourceFile`

2- if the cell content has two lines (i.e. there is a line break), the first line should be stored in `FirstLine` and returned to the calling cell while storing the second line in `SecondLine` and returning it to the right neighbor cell of the calling cell.

3- if there is no line break, `FirstLine` should be returned to the calling cell while returning empty `SecondLine` to the right neighbor cell of the calling cell.

```
Function GetTwoLines(Title As Range)
    
    Dim FirstLine, SecondLine As String, RowNum As Long
    Dim FolderPath As String: FolderPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
    Dim TargetFile As Workbook: Set TargetFile = ThisWorkbook
    Dim SheetName As String: SheetName = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name
    
    Dim SourceFile As Workbook
    
    With CreateObject("Excel.application")
        Set SourceFile = .Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & "/Source.xlsm")
    End With
    
    Dim SourceFileSearchRange As Range
    Set SourceFileSearchRange = SourceFile.Sheets(SheetName).Range("B1:B400")
    
    RowNum = WorksheetFunction.XMatch(Trim(Title.Value), SourceFileSearchRange, 0)

    'After finding the row number, I need to:
    
    '1- Get the content of the cell .Range("B" & RowNum + 1)
    '
    '2- if the cell content has two lines (i.e. there is a line break), 
    'the first line should be stored in `FirstLine` and returned to the calling cell 
    'while storing the second line in `SecondLine` and returning it to the right neighbor cell of the calling cell.

    '3- if there is no line break, `FirstLine` should be returned to the calling cell 
    'while returning empty `SecondLine` to the right neighbor cell of the calling cell.

End Function
```

I need to use the function as a UDF. For example, in some cell in `TargetFile`, I need to write in the formula bar `=GetTwoLines(C4)`, where `C4` is a `TargetFile` cell whose content is used by the function to get the two-line content of the cell `.Range("B" & RowNum + 1)` in `SourceFile`.

Comment: In which application will you use the above code? I can see `CreateObject("Excel.application")` which should not be necessary if the code will work in Excel... Why opening it in a new Excel session?

Comment: @FaneDuru I use it in `Excel`.

Comment: Do you want the function working as UDF (User Defined Function). I mean, to be called from ma cell (as formula)?

Comment: @FaneDuru I need to use it as a UDF. For example, in some cell in `TargetFile`, I need to write in the formula bar `=GetTwoLines(C4)`, where `C4` is a cell in `TargetFile` whose content is used by the function to look up for the other cell in `SourceFile`.

Comment: OK. I will place an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use the next adapted function. It can be called as UDF and returns an array. Only in this way it may affect other cell except the one where it has been called. And being a UDF function, it cannot open a workbook in the same session, indeed:

```
Function GetTwoLines(Title As Range) As Variant
    Dim FirstLine, SecondLine As String, RowNum As Variant 'mandatory to be Variant, in case of no match
    Dim FolderPath As String: FolderPath = ThisWorkbook.path
    
    Dim SourceFile As Workbook, SheetName As String
    
    Dim objExcel As Object
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.application")

       Set SourceFile = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & "\Source.xlsm")

       SheetName = Title.Parent.name 'the sheet where the range exists
    
       Dim SourceFileSearchRange As Range
       Set SourceFileSearchRange = SourceFile.Sheets(SheetName).Range("B1:B400")
    
       RowNum = Application.match(Trim(Title.value), SourceFileSearchRange, 0)
    
      Dim arrSpl
      If IsNumeric(RowNum) Then
          arrSpl = Split(SourceFileSearchRange.cells(RowNum + 1, 1).value, vbLf)
         If UBound(arrSpl) > 0 Then
            GetTwoLinesSameSess = Array(arrSpl(0), arrSpl(1)) 'if more than 2 rows, it returns only the first two...
         ElseIf UBound(arrSpl) = 0 Then
            GetTwoLinesSameSess = Array(arrSpl(0), "")
        Else
            GetTwoLinesSameSess = Array("", "Empty cell...")
         End If
      Else
         objExcel.Visible = True
         MsgBox Title.value & " could not be found in ""B1:B400"" range..."
         GetTwoLines = Array("", "not a match")
      End If
      SourceFile.Close False: objExcel.Quit
End Function
```

It can be called as UDF in the next (required) way:

```
  =GetTwoLines(C4)
```

Of course, in "C4" cell the string to be searched in the source file range...

**Edited**:

Please, use the next version which will work with the target workbook **already open** in Excel (the same session):

```
Function GetTwoLinesSameSess(Title As Range) As Variant
    Dim FirstLine, SecondLine As String, RowNum As Variant
    Dim FolderPath As String: FolderPath = ThisWorkbook.path
    
    Dim SourceFile As Workbook, SheetName As String
    
    On Error Resume Next
       Set SourceFile = Workbooks("Source.xlsm") 'set it if open already...
    On Error GoTo 0
    If SourceFile Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "The source file is not open...", vbCritical, "No source file open"
            GetTwoLinesSameSess = Array("", "No source file..."): Exit Function
    End If
    
    SheetName = Title.Parent.name 'the sheet where the range exists
    
    Dim SourceFileSearchRange As Range
    Set SourceFileSearchRange = SourceFile.Sheets(SheetName).Range("B1:B400")
    
    RowNum = Application.match(Trim(Title.value), SourceFileSearchRange, 0)
    
   Dim arrSpl
   If IsNumeric(RowNum) Then
         arrSpl = Split(SourceFileSearchRange.cells(RowNum + 1, 1).value, vbLf)
         If UBound(arrSpl) > 0 Then
            GetTwoLinesSameSess = Array(arrSpl(0), arrSpl(1)) 'if more than 2 rows, it returns only the first two...
         ElseIf UBound(arrSpl) = 0 Then
            GetTwoLinesSameSess = Array(arrSpl(0), "")
        Else
            GetTwoLinesSameSess = Array("", "Empty cell...")
         End If
   Else
        MsgBox Title.value & " could not be found in ""B1:B400"" range..."
        GetTwoLinesSameSess = Array("", "not found string...")
   End If
End Function
```

Comment: @Diaa If you tried first code I posted, please use the updated one. I kept your original declaration for `RowNum`, which must be **`Variant`** to be accepted in case of not a match found**. only using `Application.Match`. `WorksheetFunction.Match` returns a **fatal error** in case of no any match... I mean, all that to receive an eloquent message and the same returned array **in case of not a match for `Title` cell value**...

Comment: I highly appreciate your help. However, even using your last updated code, `Excel` VBA goes into [running] status for a while while being not able to respond, then this message pops up https://i.ibb.co/gvzBXv6/image.png `Microsoft Excel is waiting for another application to complete an OLE action`. I must press `Cancel` to get out of this freezing status. FYI, both workbooks are open and located in the same folder.

Comment: After debugging, `Excel` goes into this paralyzed status after executing this line `Set SourceFile = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & "/Source.xlsm")`

Comment: @Diaa If both workbooks are open, the solution should be simpler. But I would also like to understand what happens in your situation. Is it possible to not find any match of the `Title` value? Even in such a case, I am able to see a message from an Excel not visible session. If this is the case, I can adapt the code to make new Excel session `Visible`... In fact, I will do it now. Did it. Please, try the updated code and send some feedback.

Comment: Even with closed `SourceFile`, I get the same output `#VALUE!` with the same hanging [running] status.

Comment: And it should be `"\Source.xlsm"`.  Your initial way used slash instead of backslash. And, I do not know if the new session not 'want' warning you about opening it in ReadOnly way, if already open. For the sake of debugging, please close it from the active session.

Comment: @Diaa Do you have TeamViewer of AnyDesk installed? If so, I would like to connect to your computer and try understanding what's happening. The code works well in my installation...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246711/discussion-between-diaa-and-faneduru).

Comment: @Diaa Please, test the new version (after **Edited**) able to work with the open source file (the same Excel session).